# How to change props value in functional component on onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using FlatList for data display and also use the component for display.

```
<FlatList
                  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
                  data={postList}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                  refreshing={refreshing}
                  onRefresh={_onRefresh}
                />

const renderItem = (item) => {
      return(
        <FeedMainStoryCard
          feedTittle={item.item.feedTittle}
          feedimage={item.item.feedImage}
          isUserLike={item.item.isLike}
        />
      )
  }
```

And here is FeedMainStoryCard.js file

```
<TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPressHeart}
          >
            <Ionicons name={props.isUserLike === true ? "ios-heart-sharp" : "ios-heart-outline"} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

So How to change the isUserLike value on OnPress method like true and false and then change in `<Ionicons name={props.isUserLike === true ? "ios-heart-sharp" : "ios-heart-outline"} />` icon.

Please suggest any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If isUserLike is already a Boolean it would be enough with: `prop.yourBoolean` if you want to check its true otherwise:`!prop.yourBoolean`

**1st:**
**A component cannot update its own props unless they are arrays or objects (having a component update its own props even if possible is an anti-pattern), but can update its state and the props of its children.**

**2nd:**
You can add it to the children state and update its value in:

```
  const [isUserLike, setIsuserLike] = useState(props.isUserLike);

  const onPressHeart = () => {
    setIsuserLike(!isUserLike);
  };

<TouchableOpacity
         onPress={onPressHeart}>
         <Ionicons name={isUserLike ? "ios-heart-sharp" : "ios-heart-outline"} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**DEMO:** [codesandbox.io/s/boring-mcclintock-vhj4c?file=/src/App.js](http://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mcclintock-vhj4c?file=/src/App.js)

You can find more info here: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: const onPressHeart = async () => {
    !props.isUserLike
  };      but what i do on onPress?

Comment: I have edited the answer, what u have to in your function onPressHeart is convert your boolean to the opposite value

Comment: Not change value in <Ionicons name={props.isUserLike ? "ios-heart-sharp" : "ios-heart-outline"} />

Comment: how are you using the prop, i need more info

Comment: FeedMainStoryCard is component of Feed Screen.
export default function FeedMainStoryCard(props) {}
And then display the props value.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mcclintock-vhj4c?file=/src/App.js I have created a demo. I think you are missing adding it to the state so it will be listened when it change. **A component cannot update its own props unless they are arrays or objects (having a component update its own props even if possible is an anti-pattern), but can update its state and the props of its children**. Let me know if you have any doubt and dont forget to value my answer. ty :)

Comment: It is possible in array because it is not single value?

Comment: @Vicky yes, it is possible i just made the example with single value, just try to pass the exact position

Comment: It is not possible in an array.

Comment: This 'const [isUserLike, setIuserLike] = useState(props.isUserLike);' 
Only set true value in variable in first array.

Comment: I stil dont understand wwhat you mean

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** be changing the prop thats passed. You **should** instead be using states - can read more into this here: https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md.

For example you can pass the prop into a useState and toggle this value:

```
const Liker = ({ isUserLiked }) => {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(isUserLiked);

  const _onPressHeart = () => setIsLiked(!isLiked);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={_onPressHeart}>
      <Ionicons
        name={isLiked ? 'ios-heart-sharp' : 'ios-heart-outline'}
        size={30}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

You can find the full working example here: https://snack.expo.dev/@tnr_c/liker

Comment: This is not single value. It should be an array. So i think is is not possible to in variable.

Comment: State can by any type. Can you elaborate on what you mean it should be an array?

Comment: This 'const [isUserLike, setIuserLike] = useState(props.isUserLike);' Only set true value in variable in first array.

Comment: what is the other data being held in this array?

Comment: Other data is :

<FeedMainStoryCard
          feedTittle={item.item.feedTittle}
          feedimage={item.item.feedImage}
          isUserLike={item.item.isLike}
 />

Comment: The answer I provided still works. I have extended the working example link to show you a closer example to what you're working with.

Comment: Maybe this is what you mean: https://snack.expo.dev/@tnr_c/liker2. You retain the state array in the parent component and pass a onPress handler to the child which will update the state array.